# Having trouble with fscanf file pointer error

Tags: c

I've got some code here and I'm struggling with it because I can't seem to get a hold of this file pointer stuff. I'm pretty new to working with files. I've seen other questions like this and I tried the solutions that worked for others but for some reason they won't work for me. Here's the part of the code where the problem is:

```
    void writeRentals(char *filename, RentalT *allRentals, int totalRentals); 
int readRentals(char *filename, RentalT *allRentals);
void writeCars(char *filename, CarT *allCars, int totalCars);
int readCars(char *filename, CarT *allCars);

int main() {
    CarT allCars[255]; // a list of cars
    RentalT allRentals[255]; // a list of rentals
    int totalCars = 0; // number of all cars owned
    int totalRentals = 0; // number of rented cars
    int menu_choice, renterIndex, carId;
    char renterName[20], carMake[20];

    // read data from the files
    char rentalFilename[255];
    char carFilename[255];
    printf("Please enter the name of the rental records file:");
    fscanf("%s", &rentalFilename);
    printf("\nPlease enter the name of the car records file:");
    fscanf("%s", &carFilename);

    totalCars = readCars(carFilename, allCars);
    totalRentals = readRentals(&rentalFilename, allRentals);
```

And here's the errors I get when I compile it:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: gcc -g -o carRental.exe carRental.c
carRental.c: In function 'main':
carRental.c:57:9: warning: passing argument 1 of 'fscanf' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  fscanf("%s", &rentalFilename);
         ^
In file included from carRental.c:1:0:
stdio.h:385:15: note: expected 'FILE * restrict {aka struct _iobuf * restrict}' but argument is of type 'char *'
   int __cdecl fscanf(FILE * __restrict__ _File,const char * __restrict__ _Format,...) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
               ^
carRental.c:57:15: warning: passing argument 2 of 'fscanf' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  fscanf("%s", &rentalFilename);
               ^
In file included from carRental.c:1:0:
stdio.h:385:15: note: expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'char (*)[255]'
   int __cdecl fscanf(FILE * __restrict__ _File,const char * __restrict__ _Format,...) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
               ^
carRental.c:59:9: warning: passing argument 1 of 'fscanf' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  fscanf("%s", &carFilename);
         ^
In file included from carRental.c:1:0:
stdio.h:385:15: note: expected 'FILE * restrict {aka struct _iobuf * restrict}' but argument is of type 'char *'
   int __cdecl fscanf(FILE * __restrict__ _File,const char * __restrict__ _Format,...) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
               ^
carRental.c:59:15: warning: passing argument 2 of 'fscanf' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  fscanf("%s", &carFilename);
               ^
In file included from carRental.c:1:0:
stdio.h:385:15: note: expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'char (*)[255]'
   int __cdecl fscanf(FILE * __restrict__ _File,const char * __restrict__ _Format,...) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
               ^


carRental.c:62:29: warning: passing argument 1 of 'readRentals' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  totalRentals = readRentals(&rentalFilename, allRentals);
```

Any help is much appreciated thank you!

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about the error messages?

Comment: @RolandIllig The pointer stuff. I was calling it as a pointer which should've been correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up with the usage of `scanf` and `fscanf`. You missed the first argument to be passed while using fscanf.
Open a file first and Pass the corresponding file pointer as first argument to fscanf.

Use `scanf` to scan a string from console like this.

```
printf("Please enter the name of the rental records file:");
scanf("%s", rentalFilename);
//No need of &rentalFile
```

and then open this file using file pointer.

```
File *fp = fopen (rentalFilename, "r");//r for reading
```

Then you can use `fscanf` to read from file

```
fscanf(fp,"%s",line);//Note line is a char array
//This was just an example
```

You might want to look at example of `fscanf` [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm).

As suggested by chux in comments, explore various ways of scanning strings in C. Alternatives for scanf are gets(), fgets(). See which suits well for your purpose. Avoid use of deprecated methods.

Comment: There is little quality difference between suggesting  `scanf("%s", rentalFilename);` and `gets(rentalFilename);`  Recommend `scanf("%254s", rentalFilename);` or even better `fgets()`.

Comment: @Shridhar R. Kulkarni I followed your first snippet and made the scanf change. Now it compiles, but there's a logic error somewhere. I input the names of the files when prompted, but they won't open.

Comment: int readRentals(char * filename, RentalT * allRentals)
{
 FILE *fp;
 int count = 0;

 if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
 {
  printf("%s wasn't opened.\n", filename);
  return 0;
 }
  
 if (fp)
 {
  while (!feof(fp))
  {
   int c = fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d\n", allRentals[count].renterName, &allRentals[count].daysRenting, &allRentals[count].carId);
   if (c == EOF)
    break;
   count++;
  }

  if (fclose(fp))
  {
   printf("%s wasn't closed\n", filename);
  }
 }
 return count;
} //Sorry for the formatting I'm on mobile.

Comment: @NocteCaelum: "logic error somewhere" or "they won't open" doesn't give me enough information to solve your problem.  Check if the file you are trying to open exists and in proper directory. In your case input file should be in the same directory as that of code file. Also check whether information to be read is properly stored in the input file.